# Unable to login in putty using ssh mode throwing fatal error

Tags: ssh, cygwin, putty

I have installed Cygwin in my windows machine. And I want to login into cygwin using ssh mode from putty.

I have installed sshd [openSSH]service package in cygwin and it is up and running.

Now I try login Via Putty using port 22 ssh mode it throws the below error.

> PuTTY Fatal Error
>
> Couldn't agree a client-to-server cipher (available: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com)

Please help us to resolve this issue.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help writing software. You should consider asking on http://superuser.com/.

Comment: Which version of putty are you using ?

Answer (score 2):

1. Upgrading PuTTY from 5.8 to 6.0 helps sometimes.
2. One could add a supported cipher to "Ciphers" line on the server in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and then restart `sshd`, but I believe `sshd` has a reasonable defaults, so I wouldn't do that.